# Easy way to map values from list of list to dictionary

Tags: python

**Inputs**

I have two lists of lists.

```
rule_seq = 
[['#1', '#2', '#3'], 
 ['#1', '#2', '#3']]

KG_seq = 
[['nationality', 'placeOfBirth', 'locatedIn'],
 ['nationality', 'hasFather', 'nationality']]
```

I have to map the values in the same index to the dictionary with the value of rule_seq as the key in the list of above.

My desired output is

**Output**

```
unify_dict = 
{'#1': ['nationality'],
 '#2': ['placeOfBirth', 'hasFather'],
 '#3': ['locatedIn', 'nationality']}
```

I made a dictionary as follows by flattening and zipping both lists of lists to check whether keys and values are in the dictionary.

My code is as follows.

```
def create_unify_dict(rule_seq, KG_seq):
    unify_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)   
    flat_aug_rule_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(rule_seq))
    flat_aug_KG_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(KG_seq))
    
    [unify_dict[key].append(val) for key, val in zip(flat_aug_rule_list, flat_aug_KG_list) 
     if key not in unify_dict.keys() or val not in unify_dict[key]]
    
    return unify_dict

unify_dict = create_unify_dict(rule_seq, KG_seq)
```

Is there a simpler way to get the result I want?

Comment: Can you add an example where using `rule_seq` would require us to not just use `rule_seq[0]` because as it is it's just a list of duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call append using the same `defualtdict` with second level of nesting.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

for keyList,valueList in zip(rule_seq, KG_seq):
    for key,item in zip(keyList, valueList):
       if item not in result[key]: result[key].append(item)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'#1': ['nationality'],
             '#2': ['placeOfBirth', 'hasFather'],
             '#3': ['locatedIn', 'nationality']})
```

Comment: duplicated value in #1, probably check for existence before appending

Comment: @Ade_1, updated the answer, thanks for response

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections`:

```py
import collections

# Create a defaultdict with list as value type
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for s0, s1 in zip(rule_seq, KG_seq):
    for v0, v1 in zip(s0, s1):
        if v1 not in result[v0]:
            result[v0].append(v1)
        
print({k: v for k, v in result.items()})
# {
#   '#1': ['nationality'], 
#   '#2': ['placeOfBirth', 'hasFather'],
#   '#3': ['locatedIn', 'nationality'],
# }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my homemade approach using no modules. *Vanilla Python*.

```
combine = [list(set(l)) for l in [[lst[i] for lst in KG_seq] for i in range(len(KG_seq[0]))]]
dct = {place:st for place,st in zip(rule_seq[0],combine)}
```

**output**

```
{'#1': ['nationality'], '#2': ['hasFather', 'placeOfBirth'], '#3': ['nationality', 'locatedIn']}
```

**oversimplified version**

```
combine = []
for i in range(len(KG_seq[0])):
    group = []
    for lst in KG_seq:
        group.append(lst[i])
    combine.append(group)
newComb = []
for simp in combine:
    newComb.append(list(set(simp)))
dct = {}
for place,st in zip(rule_seq[0],combine):
    dct[place] = st
print(dct)
```

undersimplified

```
dct = {place:st for place,st in zip(rule_seq[0],[list(set(l)) for l in [[lst[i] for lst in KG_seq] for i in range(len(KG_seq[0]))]])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following assumptions there could be several forms to what your method look like

1. `rule_seq` and `kg_seq` are equal in length
2. `rule_seq` and `kg_seq` items are also equal in length

###### One liner

```py
def one_liner(rule_seq, kg_seq):
    ret = {}
    [ret.update({idx: ret.get(idx, set()) | {val}}) for arr_idx, arr_val in zip(rule_seq, kg_seq) for idx, val in zip(arr_idx, arr_val)]
    return ret
```

###### Single loop + one liner

```py
def one_loop(rule_seq, kg_seq):
    ret = {}
    for arr_idx, arr_val in zip(rule_seq, kg_seq):
        [ret.update({idx: ret.get(idx, set()) | {val}}) for idx, val in zip(arr_idx, arr_val)]
    return ret
```

###### Nested loops

```py
def nested_loop(rule_seq, kg_seq):
    ret = {}
    for arr_idx, arr_val in zip(rule_seq, kg_seq):
        for idx, val in zip(arr_idx, arr_val):
            ret[idx] = ret.get(idx, set()) | {val}
    return ret
```

Testing these out

```py
one_liner(rule_seq, KG_seq)

{'#1': {'nationality'},
 '#2': {'hasFather', 'placeOfBirth'},
 '#3': {'locatedIn', 'nationality'}}

one_loop(rule_seq, KG_seq)

{'#1': {'nationality'},
 '#2': {'hasFather', 'placeOfBirth'},
 '#3': {'locatedIn', 'nationality'}}

nested_loop(rule_seq, KG_seq)

{'#1': {'nationality'},
 '#2': {'hasFather', 'placeOfBirth'},
 '#3': {'locatedIn', 'nationality'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = {}
for i in range(len(rule_seq)):
    for j in range(len(rule_seq[i])):
        rule, kg = rule_seq[i][j], KG_seq[i][j]
        if (rule not in d.keys()):
            d[rule] = [kg]
        elif kg not in d[rule]:
            d[rule].append(kg)
```

result:

```
{'#1': ['nationality'], '#2': ['placeOfBirth', 'hasFather'], '#3': ['locatedIn', 'nationality']}
```